# Can no longer override documents from Document Library web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document

I discovered today that users (including myself) have suddenly lost the ability to overwrite documents from the Document Library web part. It just gives the following error:

> Sorry, there was a problem uploading this file. Please try again.

[image: problem uploading this file]

I can upload a new file without issue or alternatively I can click "See All" to go directly to the full document library and overwrite without issue there.

But for some reason, I can no longer overwrite documents from the web part.

Why would this be?

Comment: Maybe it's because some documents are open by somebody?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov - This is happening with every document in the library.

Comment: What about other users in your org? Have you tried in another browser?

Comment: @Allen_MSFT - It's happening in all browsers and as far as I can tell, all users too - including myself (SharePoint admin).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a ticket with Microsoft on the issue and per the 2 agents I spoke with, this is a new bug that many customers are reporting. They are currently working on a fix with no ETA.

Super.